# elequent belongsTo returns key instead of object on live server, but model on development machine

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationships

I have some Models in Laravel, but one of them is behaving strange...

---

this is kinda embarrassing,

I have somehow managed to have different colum names on my production server from my Development machine... on my Development machine, the column is called creation_id, but on my production machine, it is called creation...

---

I have a Creation that has many Events
the event belongs to the Creation and hasMany eventAttendees
the eventAttendees belongs to events, and can access the creation->title that is is grand parent for convenience

on my Development machine, everything is working as I would expect, but on my live server, I get the id instead of the creation from Event->creation...

notice, that EventAttende->getEventCreationTitleAttribute works until 'getCreationTitleAttribute', this Means that EventAttende->event() works...

I am using laravel 4.1

This is the relevant code, the getCreationTitleAttribute is called from frozenNodes administrator

```
// Filename: /app/models/Event.php
<?php
namespace XXX;
class Event extends \Eloquent 
{
    protected $connection = 'legacy';

    public function creation()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('XXX\Creation', 'creation_id');
    }

    public function getCreationTitleAttribute()
    {
        $x = $this->creation; // I have also tried $this->creation()->first() which returns null on live server

        // This should be the normal behaviour, the test shouldn't even be necessary
        // And the test wasn't there before i uploaded to my live server
        if (is_object($x))
            return $x->title;

        // This is the flow I would expect, 
        // and the flow I get on my production machine...
        return $x;
    }

    public function eventAttende()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('XXX\EventAttende');
    }
}

// Filename: /app/models/Creation.php
<?php
namespace XXX;
class Creation extends \Eloquent 
{
    protected $connection = 'legacy';

    public function Creation()
    {
        $this->bgColor="FFFFFF";
        $this->textColor="000000";
        $this->linkColor="0000FF";
    }

    public function events()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('XXX\Event');
    }
}

// Filename: /app/models/EventAttende.php
<?php
namespace XXX;
class EventAttende extends \Eloquent 
{
    protected $connection = 'legacy';

    // this works
    public function event()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('XXX\Event', 'event');
    }

    public function getEventCreationTitleAttribute()
    {
        return $this->event()->first()->creationTitle;
    }
}
```

I am using frozennodes administrator to show the data. (The business code is an older legacy platform, so I don't use the data from laravel yet.)

the column definition part that uses the attribute is this:

```
/**
 * The display columns
 */
'columns' => array(
    'id',
    'creation_title' => array(
        'title' => 'Kreation',
        //'name_field' => 'full_name',
        //'type' => 'relationship',
        //'relationship' => 'creation',
    ),
    'name' => array(
        'title' => 'Navn'
    ),

),
```

Comment: First off, you need that check, because relation `creation` returns either `Model` or `null`. And probably this is the problem, not returning `id`. The latter could happen if you had both relation and table column witht the same name (which wouldn't return `id` but that column value).

Comment: Hello Jarek, there is no column called creation in the event table, the foreign key is named creation_id.

Comment: Show the execution code then

Comment: As i mentioned, the problem is not that the relation returns null, which would be understandable... unlikely since creations can't be deleted and event belongs to creations... The problem is that it returns the id on my live server instead of the object as on my production machine

Comment: I am using frozenNodes administrator to show the data... so I simply have set up the column 'view' definitions. Se my edit in a few seconds.

Comment: You know, without seeing the code I doubt anyone can help. I don't know frozennode so I won't be guessing, but local/live difference is likely to happen when you run `composer update` instead `composer install` which fetches probably newer version of the package and maybe its behaviour changed. Make sure the version is the same.

Comment: Oh boy... I was about to write an example to you with a simple route... I figured out the difference. I have somehow managed to have different colum names on my production server from my Development machine... on my Development machine, the column is called creation_id, but on my production machine, it is called creation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had somehow managed to have different colum names on my production server from my Development machine...

- on my Development machine, the column is called creation_id,
- on my production machine, it is called creation...